# different content based on choice on homepage

Tags: 7

I would like to make a homepage where an anonymous visitor makes a choice (teacher or student). Based on this choice an adapted menu should be visible, and the visitor has access to specific pages.

I know this is easily done if a visitor has to register, but it's just a website with some text and documents, nothing special. So asking the visitor to register before having this information is serious overshooting. I am looking for a way to influence the display of pages just by a choice made once per visit.

Does anyone know if there is a module for this? Or is there another way to do this?

Many thanks.
Steven

Comment: Could you not just output both menus and hide them with css, then use some simple javascript to display the relevant menu depending on which option is selected?

Comment: I don't see how I can do this. The choice on the homepage should be remembered during the visit on the website.

Comment: set a cookie or session variable